# Is it possible to send many requests asynchronously with Python

Tags: python, django, http, asynchronous, slack-api

I'm trying to send about 70 requests to slack api but can't find a way to implement it in asynchronous way, I have about 3 second for it or I'm getting `timeout error`

here how I've tried to t implement it:

```
import asyncio

def send_msg_to_all(sc,request,msg):
    user_list = sc.api_call(
       "users.list"
    )
members_array = user_list["members"]

ids_array = []
for member in members_array:
    ids_array.append(member['id'])
real_users = []

for user_id in ids_array:

    user_channel = sc.api_call(
        "im.open",
        user=user_id,
    )
    if user_channel['ok'] == True:
        real_users.append(User(user_id, user_channel['channel']['id']) )

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(send_msg(sc, real_users, request, msg))
loop.close()
return HttpResponse()


async def send_msg(sc, real_users, req, msg):
    for user in real_users:    
        send_ephemeral_msg(sc,user.user_id,user.dm_channel, msg)


def send_ephemeral_msg(sc, user, channel, text):
    sc.api_call(
        "chat.postEphemeral",
        channel=channel,
        user=user,
        text=text
    )
```

But it looks like I'm still doing it in a synchronous way

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Your code has syntax error, lines below `send_msg_to_all` function declaration have no indentations. Please fix your code first.

Answer (score 0):

Slack's API has a rate limit of 1 query per second (QPS) as [documented here](https://api.slack.com/docs/rate-limits).

Even if you get this working you'll be well exceeding the limits and you will start to see `HTTP 429 Too Many Requests` errors. Your API token may even get revoked / cancelled if you continue at that rate.

I think you'll need to find a different way.